# Searching in MySQL using REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm creating a search function using query like this

```
SELECT personal_info.PersonalID, personal_info.FullName FROM personal_info

INNER JOIN skillset ON personal_info.PersonalID = skillset.PersonalID
INNER JOIN language ON personal_info.PersonalID = language.PersonalID

WHERE personal_info.FullName LIKE '%%'
AND skillset.SkillName REGEXP 'pl|google'
AND language.Language REGEXP 'ita|vol'

HAVING COUNT(*)
```

This query return results as I expected, but, when I changed it to make sure

again by change the `skillset.Skillname REGEXP 'pl|google'` into `skillset.Skillname REGEXP 'pl|adafrtesd'`

It return the same value when I supposed it will not return anything, anyone can help? I'm still learning MySQL. :D

My table structure:

skillset
PersonalID |  SkillName
130105     |  PL
130105     |  Google

language
PersonalID  |  Language
130105      |  Italia
130105      |  Volapuk

Comment: The `|` in a regex means `OR`.  So both `'pl|google'` and `'pl|adafrtesd'` will match `'pl'`.

Comment: Is that wrong?  Are you trying to match something else instead?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: It will not return anything if there is no record with `skillname` either `pl` or `adafrtesd`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills What should I do if I wanted to search both of pl and google using regex? Example: skillset.SkillName LIKE '%PL%' and skillset.SkillName LIKE '%Google%'

Comment: @Xtrader and what's wrong with what you just wrote?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It returns 0, haha. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do *specifically*?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I want to search from the table that must has SkillName "pl" and "google" and I also wanted it to have "italia" and "volapuk". So if it only have 1 SkillName (either pl/google) it will return nothing and so do with the language. Sorry for confusing question. :(

Comment: @Xtrader by "table" you mean "row?"  There is no row that has both "pl" *and* "google," so your query will fail as you expect

Comment: @ExplosionPills Ah yes, I mean row, what I trying to do is to search every row that match my criteria (pl and google)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24903/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-xtrader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare two rows of the same table in one query without aggregation.  It would be a better idea to select all valid possible rows from MySQL and loop through the data with PHP as you will be able to maintain state (e.g. which person has what skill) and then match the final results against the request.

In MySQL, you could potentially do it with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT personal_info.PersonalID, personal_info.FullName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Language ORDER BY Language) AS languages,
    GROUP_CONCAT(SkillName ORDER BY SkillName) AS skills
FROM personal_info
JOIN skillset ON personal_info.PersonalID = skillset.PersonalID
JOIN language ON personal_info.PersonalID = language.PersonalID
AND skillset.SkillName REGEXP 'pl|google'
AND language.Language REGEXP 'ita|vol'
GROUP BY PersonalID
HAVING
    skills LIKE '%pl%' AND skills LIKE '%google%'
```